# Devo declarar uma variável dentro da condição do "if" ou separado?

Tags: php, if, condição

Preciso chamar uma função que pode retornar falso ou um valor, e caso ela retorne o valor preciso manipulá-lo.

Então fiz um código parecido com o abaixo:

```
//A função que é chamada é muito mais complexa do que essa, estou utilizando apenas como exemplo para a demonstração.
public function divisao($a,$b){
    if($b > 0){
        return $a / $b;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


//Em outro trecho do código
....
if($resultado = divisao($variavel1,$variavel2)){
   //Faça alguma coisa com o resultado
}else{
   //Faça outra coisa
}
...
```

A minha pergunta dando foco para o último `if` seria: **é uma boa prática colocar o retorno da função já atribuindo ele à variável e testando tudo na mesma linha (dentro do `if`)?** Caso não seja, qual o motivo de não ser uma boa prática?

Sei que o código poderia ser escrito da seguinte forma:

```
$resultado = divisao($variavel1,$variavel2);
if($resultado){
   //Faça alguma coisa com o resultado
}else{
   //Faça outra coisa
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Há controvérsias quanto ao assunto foco da pergunta.

Algumas pessoas consideram que isto fica menos legível. Alguns estabeleceram uma regra que tudo o que gera efeito colateral (alteração de estado) deve ficar em uma linha separada de forma mais clara, afinal mudança de estado equivocado costuma ser o maior motivo de geração de *bugs* e onde mais tem que depurar (note que um processo de *debug* o tempo todo você fica olhando a mudança do estado das variáveis pra ver o que aconteceu).

Por outro lado pode ser um pouco de exagero seguir a regra cegamente. Será que é tão difícil visualizar que tem uma atribuição ali?

Mas também podemos pender para o outro lado novamente. Será que o que voê queria fazer era comparar a variável com o retorno da função, ou seja, queria usar `==` que é o operador de comparação e e não de atribuição?

O que você ganha de fato colocando na mesma linha? Se não tiver um ganho muito claro não use. Pelo jeito do seu código parece que quer ganhar digitação, o que é uma coisa boba, aí não é um bom motivo.

Na verdade estou mais preocupado com o retorno de valores de tipos diferentes na função. Uma linguagem dinâmica permite isto, mas deveria? Será que funciona bem? veja uma situação que não funciona:

```
<?php
function subtracao($a, $b){
    if ($b > 0) return $a - $b;
    else return false;
}
if ($resultado = subtracao(4, 4)) echo "entrou";
else echo "não entrou";
if ($resultado = subtracao(4, 0)) echo "entrou";
else echo "não entrou";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dJHBCB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MixingType). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/MixingType.php).

Então esqueça esse negócio do boa prática, entenda as motivações pra usar uma coisa ou outra. Veja se tem problema real.

Comment: Excelente a sua explicação.

Comment: Sobre a questão do tipo de retorno, a situação não é semelhante ao uso de tipos *nullable* em linguagens tipadas? O uso desses tipos pode ser um problema nelas?

Comment: Não exatamente, é um problema, mas aparente, porque quebra a aplicação (em linguagens modernas, como C# 8, já indica em compilação que vai dar problema), em PHP só executa algo de um jeito não esperado e errado. Mas o problema não é a linguagem ser dinâmica, é ser fraca. Se ela tivesse tipagem forte, mesmo sendo dinâmica, daria um erro porque receber um 0 onde se espera um booleano quebra a tipagem. Retornar tipos diferents não é problema, tratar dois tipos como se fosse a mesma coisa é problema.

Answer (score 3):

## Sobre o uso das boas práticas

Algo "Ideal" é relativo quando se trata de práticas de programação, mas em vez de discutir sobre isso vou tentar responder de forma objetiva. Acho a pergunta perninente pelo fato de você estar buscando ter uma visão diferente sobre o código e buscar aprender com isso. **É importante lembrar que isso muitas vezes é uma questão de gosto e, portanto, não é uma unanimidade entre os programadores**. Sabendo disso, segue a resposta para cada caso citado.

---

### Primeiro caso

Para simplificar o código, você poderia utilizar a técnica **Early Return** que consiste em retornar antes para evitar o uso de um `else`. Por exemplo:

```
if($b > 0){
    return $a / $b;
}

return false;
```

Você também poderia inverter a lógica e continuar aplicando o Early Return:

```
if($b === 0){
   return false;
}

return $a / $b;
```

Lembrando mais uma vez que isso é mais uma questão de gosto do que de "certo" ou "errado". Deixar de utilizar `else` é uma opção, mas não siga nenhuma prática rigidamente se não for vantajoso.

---

### Segundo caso

Você pode atribuir e testar a variável ao mesmo tempo dentro da expressão testada no `if`, no entanto isso não parece muito legível. Por isso atribuir um valor para a variável `$resultado` primeiro e depois testar parece uma opção melhor.

Deixar tudo em uma mesma linha deixa o código confuso as vezes, o PHP permite isso e quando essa prática é feita em exagero parece que o código passou por uma minificação do Javascript, o que é péssimo para legibilidade.

Comment: Muitos códigos meus eu faço uso do Early Return. Por uma questão de gosto, eu acho que fica um pouco mais claro o código. Mas, como dito pela ótima explicação do @Maniero eu não vejo problemas em usar mais de um `if` se necessário. Faço uso de `else if` inclusive. =)